# Magento 2 Elasticsearch / Elasticsuite - no products in category

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

We have a mysterious elasticsearch issue on a 2.3.6 Magento site.
We have Elasticsearch 7.x installed with Elasticsuite. This has worked for years. Suddenly the catalog_product indices on all four store instances show 0 docs in there.

We reinstalled Elasticsuite, reindexed a million times, checked settings etc. There are no errors in the system.log or the elasticsearch.log

There's enough memory on the server.
I'm running out of ideas what else to check for. Any suggestions anyone?

MORE INFO:
indices:

```
green  open   fblive_en_catalog_category_20230309_095846 -sqoWpBNQ0OeAkm3MPsGJA   1   0         16            0     51.5kb         51.5kb
green  open   fblive_it_catalog_product_20230309_095836  n2HOZwWVTYOIahlLcRRI4g   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_de_catalog_product_20230309_095819  CMeLNqmvQNWUzjuER-wJmA   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_en_tracking_log_event_202303        K_ilbCWDRduApRCyst8a_w   1   0         15            0     36.1kb         36.1kb
green  open   fblive_it_catalog_category_20230309_095847 tFcrAbCWRb20UbWgCd3LbQ   1   0         16            0     55.1kb         55.1kb
green  open   fblive_de_thesaurus_20230309_095847        QzCtUzl-TmKBrjj-6XUOQQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_it_thesaurus_20230309_095847        KKHJUjhERuCnk3-uQYvVnQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_de_tracking_log_session_202303      ihro1vbVQwCT9d9doCGR1Q   1   0          1            0      4.9kb          4.9kb
green  open   fblive_de_tracking_log_event_202303        8aJZ7lRNS9q3iVvRuJEW3Q   1   0          2            0     14.9kb         14.9kb
green  open   fblive_en_catalog_product_20230309_095808  wLjsBQSVR-621pqMDl4shg   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_fr_catalog_product_20230309_095828  dX1G-LmYTzemm7dnLDVPGQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_en_thesaurus_20230309_095847        S3puShOORhCfAdZC71tkMQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_fr_thesaurus_20230309_095847        afxk6-OCQmK8izdyWtQUPg   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   fblive_fr_catalog_category_20230309_095846 HaNivjRVSx-lBd2GtORvCQ   1   0         16            0     57.3kb         57.3kb
green  open   fblive_en_tracking_log_session_202303      xTq8HVocTJKiOMmAn91ejg   1   0          4            0     12.2kb         12.2kb
green  open   fblive_de_catalog_category_20230309_095846 eAVBMVhWQl2Y3OENmiEghQ   1   0         16            0     52.9kb         52.9kb
```

Comment: Let's check the elasticsearch:

What is the Elasticsearch version?

Can you share `GET _cat/indices?v`

call the `POST _all/_refresh` API and check the `GET _cat/indices?v` again

Comment: we have been banging our head with this for ages. It worked fine in a staging environment, we synced the products, reindexed and same again. The indices all show as docs number 0. we have multiple times completely deleted the indices and reindexed. now trying to amend the mapping as we finally got an error in the log about the type of a status attribute that is expected to be boolean, but should be text because it gets '1'. Any further ideas?

Comment: If you can give an information about my question I can tell you what is happening :)

Comment: Added the indices above - after a refresh, looks exactly the same.

Comment: What is the Elasticsearch version?

Comment: Elasticsearch version: 7.7.0

Comment: This is the error we're having now: main.ERROR: Bulk index operation failed 1 times in index fblive_it_catalog_product_20230309_095836 for type _doc. Error (mapper_parsing_exception) : failed to parse field [status] of type [boolean] in document with id '14008'. Preview of field's value: '1'. Failed doc ids sample : 14008. [] []                  however this did works absolutely fine on the local dev setup. tried to change the status type to text via elasticseach_indices.xml but whatever we put doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the error. It looks like elasticsearch v7 is NOT compatible with magento 2.3.6. Use elasticsearch v6.x
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/search-elasticsearch.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252406/discussion-between-rita-and-musab-dogan).